# insert a list of records into table using loop (mysql, php)

Tags: php, mysql

i've 2 tables. In `table_1` i've got different tasks that is updated every day. And in `table_2` i've got list of workers. I need automatically and randomly assign 1 worker(table_2) to 1 task(table_1), so that every worker will have approximately the same amount of tasks.

I've tried to use `rand()` method, it assigns randomly but not equally, i mean one worker can have more tasks to do than another one. then i've tried to use `count()` method, but couldn't connect them... I'm new in php and mysql :(

i made something like this but only in mysql, but it works only once because of (not in) function.

```
insert into table_1(worker) 
    select col_1 from table_2 
    where col_1 not in (select worker from table_1) 
    order by col_1 rand() 
    limit 0,1;
```

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: I think you want to randomize the order of the list of tasks, then hand them out evenly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have 2 solutions for you. The first is simpler, but only if you can modify table_2 to add a field for the number of tasks currently assigned. It would be a counter that you would initialize to 0 and then increment every time you assign a task. If you can modify your table, this would select a worker that has the fewest tasks assigned:

```
select worker_id, MIN(tasks_assigned)
FROM table_2
GROUP BY worker_id
```

This is a round robin assigner, but it isn't all that random. I would think equitable assignments is more important though. If you can't alter your tables, the same solution is a bit more messy:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE task_list
( worker_id INT,
  tasks_assigned INT )

SELECT INTO task_list
  SELECT worker_id, count(worker_id) AS tasks_assigned
  FROM table_1
  GROUP BY worker_id

SELECT INTO task_list
  SELECT worker_id, 0 
  FROM table_2
  WHERE worker_id NOT IN (SELECT worker_id FROM task_list)

SELECT worker_id MIN(tasks_assigned) 
FROM task_list
GROUP BY worker_id
```

Obviously this isn't the entire solution. But this will give you a worker_id that has the fewest number of tasks assigned. You'll then have to use this id to do an update to your task table (table_1)

Answer (score 0):

To do the random assignment of tasks I would first randomize the tasks and then hand them out to workers by simply iterating through a list of worker arrays and attaching a task to them as you go, one by one. Here's an idea of what I mean. Obviously I dont have the full details of your code but I hope it helps.

```
// assuming you already have a list of tasks and workers fetched from the database
// and flattened into simple integer indexed arrays. I'll call them $workers 
// and $tasks

// create an array of tasks per worker
$worker_tasks = array();

// randomize the tasks
shuffle($tasks); // built in php function
while(!empty($tasks)){
    foreach($workers as $worker){
        if(empty($tasks)) break;

        // add a new task under the worker
        $worker_tasks[$worker][] = array_pop($tasks);
    }
}

// insert the array of worker_tasks into w/e table you want.
// high five everyone
```

Comment: that would assign one task per worker and leave remaining tasks unassigned. From what I understand from the original question I think it would be better to do a `while(!empty($tasks)) {workers[i][] = array_pop($tasks); $i = ($i + 1) % len($workers);}` that would assign tasks in order to each worker leaving no tasks unassigned.

Comment: @Toote +1 You are absolutely right. I didnt think too hard on this and missed an obvious bug.